# Use column alias in GROUP BY

Tags: oracle, group-by, alias

I have a query where I chain two columns. Why does the alias **not** work in the `GROUP BY` clause but in `ORDER BY` clause, it does work? How can I write the select correctly?

```
SELECT
  KOS_VER_ID        AS "Vertrag"
  , WHR_ISO_3_CODE  AS "Waehrung"
  , KOS_KOA_ST_KZN || '  -  ' || ST_LANGBEZ_EN as "Kostenart"
  , SUM (KOS_BETRAG) AS "Summe pro KOA"
FROM
  KOSTEN
  , WAEHRUNG
  , SCHLUESSELTABELLE
WHERE 
  KOSTEN.KOS_VERHI_WHR_ID = WAEHRUNG.WHR_ISO_ID
  AND KOSTEN.KOS_KOA_ST_KZN = SCHLUESSELTABELLE.ST_ID
  AND KOS_VER_ID in (2509, 2510, 2511)
GROUP BY
  KOS_VER_ID
  , WHR_ISO_3_CODE
  , KOS_KOA_ST_KZN || '  -  ' || ST_LANGBEZ_EN
ORDER BY
  "Vertrag"
  , "Kostenart"
;
```

Comment: It is Oracle 11g

Comment: It's also better (and probably more correct) to use `GROUP BY a, b` than `GROUP BY a || '  -  ' || b`

Comment: Thanks, it works with `group by a, b`.   Do you know, why "Vertrag" doesn't work in the section `GROUP BY`?

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name has already answered on that. See also a similar question at SO (shameless self-promotion;) : [Using 'case expression column' in where clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545664/using-case-expression-column-in-where-clause/6545685#6545685)

Answer (score 8):

> *Why does the alias not work in the GROUP BY clause*?

Because these simply are the syntax rules. A column alias may be used in the `ORDER BY` clause but not in the `GROUP BY` clause.

If you look at the syntax diagrams this becomes obvious:

[The `order by` clause is defined as](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#i2168299):[image]

So after the `ORDER BY` an expression is allowed, a position (`order by 1`) or a `c_alias` which stands for "column alias".

[The `group by` is defined as](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#i2065777):

[image]

As you can see, no `c_alias` option after it, so you can't use a column alias.

This is nothing special to Oracle though. This is how it was defined in the SQL standard.

Answer (score 4):

The syntax restrictions mentioned by @a_horse_with_no_name are merely a reflection of how the query is logically processed by the SQL database engine:

1. The `FROM` clause is processed and all required tables are
   identified, after possibly resolving view definitions.
2. The `WHERE` clause is processed, applying predicates to the table rows.
3. The `GROUP BY` clause is processed, applying aggregate functions to the rows remaining after the `WHERE`.
4. The `HAVING` clause is processed, applying additional predicates to the output of `GROUP BY`.
5. Only now the `SELECT` list is processed, retrieving the requested columns and possibly assigning aliases to them.
6. The `ORDER BY` clause is processed and, since it comes after the `SELECT` list processing, it has access to the aliases assigned thereby.

Comment: I added the word "logically" before the "processed". Because the implementation and actual processing is often different.

Answer (score 1):

Code evaluation follows the 
**Logical Processing Order of the SELECT statement** .

Aliases can be used only if they were introduced in the preceding step. So aliases in the `SELECT` clause can be used in the ORDER BY but not the `GROUP BY` clause.

**Reference**: [Microsoft T-SQL Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#logical-processing-order-of-the-select-statement) for further reading.

1. FROM
2. ON
3. JOIN
4. WHERE
5. GROUP BY
6. WITH CUBE or WITH ROLLUP
7. HAVING
8. SELECT
9. DISTINCT
10. ORDER BY
11. TOP

Hope this helps.

Also, [Related discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51886323/4967895)