# Oracle: sub select with AS, COALESCE, GROUP BY, HAVING CASE WHEN and ORDER BY

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

I am typing the below code and it is returning me "ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected". What is happening?

```sql
    SELECT
       max(alias.id) AS "id",
       (SELECT alias.name FROM EXAM WHERE alias.id = alias.id ) AS "REF",
       alias.name
      
       
       FROM EXAM alias
       GROUP BY alias.name
       ORDER BY alias.name ASC;
```

Here's a fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/537e2/1

Comment: You probably should study the difference between quoted identifiers and character literals. Also, check [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/104539/use-column-alias-in-group-by) out.

Comment: I visited the link but could not resolve the issue.

Comment: @mustaccio do You can help me?

Comment: What is the subquery supposed to do? You already have the `alias.name` column, your GROUP BY is based on it. Why do you need an extra subquery?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ the subquery is just an example I created. Actually I want to learn how to make it work in Oracle. Because I can only do it in mySQL. 
But whenever I try it returns the error "ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected"

Comment: What do you want us to make work? The subquery doesn't make sense. `WHERE alias.id = alias.id` will always be true. So do you want every row from `exam`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'COLUMN PREFIX'` is a scalar string, not a valid (alias) column name. Oracle (flagship, not MySQL) uses Double Quotes for such object names. (The `ORA` error indicates you are using the flagship product)

Oracle does not distinguish between `NULL` and `''`. anything compared to `NULL` is *unknown*. Your `case` statement will always go to the `else` clause.

I don't think Oracle allows you to use a column alias in the `having` or `group by` clause.  I can't test right now.